# How can I return array in golang to use it in my index.html?

Tags: go

I have this code

```
files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir("public/my-template/imagesT/gallery/")
    for _, f:=range files {
        fmt.Println(f.Name())
    }
```

How can  return an array contain all `f.Name` to use them in index.html ?

Answer (score 2):

Create a slice and use `append` to add the file names in your loop.

```
var fileNames []string
files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir("public/my-template/imagesT/gallery/")
for _, f := range files {
    fileNames = append(fileNames, f.Name())
}

// Now fileNames contains all of the file names for you to pass to your template.
```

Also note that you should not ignore the possible error returned on the line

```
files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir("public/my-template/imagesT/gallery/")
```

Comment: i want to say that when i passed files in this code    controller.carService.InsertImages(&fileNames) and the InsertImages function     func (r CarService) InsertImages(images *[]string) {
 session, _ := mgo.Dial(r.uri)
 defer session.Close()
 session.SetSafe(&mgo.Safe{})
 collection := session.DB(r.dbName).C(r.collectionName)
 for _, image := range images {
  error := collection.Insert(

   models.Car{ImagePath:image})
  if error != nil {

  }
 }

} i have error say : cannot range over images (type *[]string)